# PostgreSQL installation always stuck in the last step

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation

[image]

my os is win7 x64,version of postgreSQL is postgreSQL9.6.8;I have tries many times,but it's always stuck in last step;please help me

Comment: I am getting the same problem. I am getting a hunch that the port 5432 is blocked for some reason.

Comment: @khinggan Have you found any solution?